# SQL Server data tool installation stuck after 80% of installation since 5 hours

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, installation, ssis

Recently I have installed sql server then was not able to create sql server integration project using sql server integration import project wizard.so uninstalled Visual studio, sql server data tools.

Now I have installed visual studio 2019. which was installed successfully and then started to installed sql server data tools. Which downloaded successfully and stuck after 80% of installation.

Please check below screenshot
[image]

Comment: Do you have a lot of `ngen.exe` processes appearing and disappearing in your Task Manager? It's probably busy recompiling all of the .NET Assemblies in the GAC - the slower your discs are the longer it will take.

Answer (score 1):

After 5 hours, I looked in task manager and I don't know how their were 2 .exe was running.I changed priority to high for first one and ended second .exe task and sql server data tools installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer.

My corporate antivirus was likely fighting with the ssis Installer. After watching each of the executables peek the cpu on my machine back and fourth for 60 minutes and trying a reboot..ect.. I decided to disconnect from the internet.

This seemed to calm the security software and allow the installer to do it's thing.